# How to recover a Yahoo account?

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo, password-recovery, yahoo-account

Someone was hacked, the hacker changed the password, we tried resetting it. Yahoo says:

> Looks like we can't recover your account online. Please visit our help
>   site to get back in.

What now? We [submitted this form](https://io.help.yahoo.com/contact/index?y=PROD_ACCT&page=contactform&locale=en_US&token=Zh%2FBBVqXzLHlIbokbUqVWTUbuuQeXGkGnZzhKR2JQ4O6mMQdy9JSWfJCJWvc4C3%2F4ml2UKrHQ0nko7rLtSR524NwvUtZOo0Gj805mARbzr8vfgnNVTA8e9O5KtKpyg0HCTiJHUPMwrZY3nJcM3QshA45uqklXHRB&selectedChannel=email-icon&yid=), anything else that can be done? And how long does it take for Yahoo to reply to our request?

Comment: Related issue http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87715/how-to-report-scam-gmail-acount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of doing anything else. Hopefully they will respond. Time they will take from 24 hours to 1 week depends on query.

Comment: Ok thanks, will accept the answer as soon as they reply, if you could also answer this, it would be great http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87715/how-to-report-scam-gmail-acount