# How to report a scam Gmail acount?

Tags: gmail, phishing

A [Yahoo account was hacked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87712/how-to-recover-a-yahoo-account). Let's assume it was called `example@yahoo.com` and that the victim also has another email `example@gmail.com`.

The guy who hacked the Yahoo email ID stole the contact list, and created `examplee@gmail.com` and began sending scam email to the contact list. What to do about it?

To clarify:

Say my email is `lynob@gmail.com`, a hacker created `lynobb@gmail.com`, and began sending scams to my contacts.

I do know the email account that the hacker created, it's a Gmail account, but can't report phishing or spam cause he didn't send me a copy (reporting emails in Gmail is only an option if you receive a spam email. You cannot report a spam email that never contacted you).

And my contacts won't report him cause they think it's me, they won't notice `lynobb@gmail.com`, they won't notice the difference, also the hacker is using my profile picture as a profile picture for the scam Gmail.

Comment: Related issue http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87712/how-to-recover-a-yahoo-account

Comment: I don't know that there's anything you can do to get Google to take action. It's not like it's a social media account that is impersonating you. At best, contacting your contacts yourself and letting them know someone is impersonating you may be all you can do. Depending on the nature of the scam, you may have grounds for a lawsuit or to pursue criminal charges, in which case the information to track down the scammer can be subpoenaed, but I'm not a lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (as a victim) can't do anything about this because you don't know what email address hacker is using to send scam emails (it might be Gmail, Yahoo, Rediff anything with anyname).

What you can do is if you’re getting unwanted emails, you can **block** the sender, **unsubscribe** from the sender, or **report** the message depending on the type of email.

Other people also can follow the same.

In Gmail to report about unwanted email:

> - Open Gmail.
> - Open the email you'd like to report.
> - At the top right of the message next to the Reply button, click the down arrow.
> - Select **Report Phishing**.

For more information: [Block unwanted emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8151?hl=en).

Comment: I do know what email address the hacker is using, it's a gmail

Comment: How to report in Gmail, I have mentioned in answer.

Comment: but what if the hacker didnt send me a copy? so i cant report phishing and my contacts won't bother to report phishing cause they thing it's me

Comment: About that you can't do anything. You can just inform to all your contacts (if possible) that you are using `example@gmail.com` email id, if they get any email with other email id with your name, ignore that email or report about that.